# Failure to run Python code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I have installed Python and Code Runner to be able to run my Python code. I get an error whenever I try to run my Python code. When I press "Select Python interpreter" in the purple bar below, I then try to choose one(Python 3.8.1 32-bit), but another error comes up again saying "Failed to set 'pythonPath'.....".

The error when trying to run the code says: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Please help, what should I do?

Comment: just remember all caps when you're spelling the mans name https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noPlIn8TJSQ. Also I'm not sure but maybe try setting your environment variable.

Comment: @Warlax56 thank you, I have tried doing that, but it still doesn't work, I might be doing it wrong. May you clarify step by step on how I could set my environmental variable? But also which one should I edit between "User variables for user" and "System variables", they are all found in the environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in VS Code, as a code editor, it needs to find python installed outside VS Code to run python code. Therefore, we need to ensure that python is available:

[image]

Please check whether the python environment variable contains "Python 3.8.1" you are using. And please reopen VS Code after setting.

[image]

Reference: [python environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).

Comment: Thank you, concerning the availability of python outside the visual studio code, it is there and the command line proves it well. But I would like to get more clarification about the environmental variables, I have tried editing, it still doesn't work. But I think I'm doing it wrong. Also in the environmental variable, I have two parts, "User variables for user" and "System variables". Which exactly am I supposed to edit? Can I please have a step by step clarification on this. I think it is where the problem is. Thank you!

Comment: @boss -I am using "User variables for user", you could also check the "Add pythonX to Path" option when installing python. You can refer to the content of this link: [python environment variables.](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might be because python is not added to your path.
To edit your system variables do the following:

> 1. Search for system variables in your win search bar. This should open this window.
>    [image]

> 2. Click on `Environment Variables` and then select `Path` from `System Variables`.
>    [image]

> 3. Click on `Edit`. Now add a field there containing the complete address to your Python Script folder like this.
>    The path should look like this
>    `C:\Users\{your username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\`

> [image]

> 4. Click on ok and check by typing python in your vscode integrated terminal.